# Update column value in entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my database, I have around 30 tables, each with an `emp_number (INT)` column.

How can I update the value of `emp_number` in all 30 tables?

Comment: Do it via dynamic sql. But take care of order if you have relation defined on that column'

Comment: i feel compelled to say - oof normalization issue.  you might take this opportunity to fix the schema.

Comment: what is the database server you are using , SQL Server? SYBASE? ORACLE?...

Comment: I am also waiting for @SurendraNathGM question's answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use a long single query, for example:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, table3, ...
SET
  table1.emp_number = 30,
  table2.emp_number = 30,
  table3.emp_number = 30,
  ...
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de703/1).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, execute this:

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_name, ' SET emp_number = 30;')
FROM columns
WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabase'
AND column_name = 'emp_number'
```

To get an output like so:

[image]

Then execute the resulting queries.

If you need to run the query from PHP or similar, write it into a stored procedure.

Comment: The basic idea behind this will work with other DBMS as well (might need to adjust the query though)

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you're using MS SQL:

```
sp_msforeachtable " UPDATE ? SET emp_number='YOUR VALUE'"
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the best possible answer, you should include which RDBMS you are using.  Regardless, I believe this is fairly generic:

You can get a list of the tables that contain the column using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'emp_number'
```

Then, use a `cursor` to go through the list of of tables and dynamically create and run the update statements for each table.

Comment: Yes, But i needed update query to update the COLUMN in entire database

Comment: With that update query it should reflect to all column values in all tables.